# XSD to JAXB file and JAXB to JPA entity class with database relationship

Tags: java, jpa, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I am trying to create JPA entity classes from xsd files. I convert xsd files to JAXB files using xjc command. But i can't convert JAXB to JPA entity classes. I can't use the hyperJAXB because most of the links are broken and i didn't find any tutorial to use hyperjaxb.

Is there a link between JPA entities with JAXB classes to create relationship to database tables?

Can you share any working links to help my project or any tutorial?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/wiki. There are two tutorial there.

Comment: I see this tutorial but it says download the basic project tamplete. The basic project tamplete does not download any zip file. Like that https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/wiki/Downloads . I can't run the hyperjaxb3 in java project because some of the packages are deleted.

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/releases

Answer (score 0):

To [demonstrate (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-hyperjaxb-ejb-sample-po-initial-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip), this [project](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/tree/master/ejb/assembly/samples/po-initial#readme) uses the [HiSrc HyperJAXB Maven Plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb#readme) to read sample XML Schema (xsd) file(s) and XML Schema Binding (xjb) file(s) to generate Java Entity classes with JPA and JAXB annotations.